# Subtracting two COUNT values in SQL

Tags: sql

EDIT: UPDATED
Is it possible to subtract the results from query 1 with query 2, in one query?

```
SELECT  
    FlightID, COUNT(*) AS 'Available Seats'  
FROM 
    AircraftSeating 
INNER JOIN 
    Flight ON Flight.FlightAircraftID = AircraftSeating.AircraftID
WHERE 
    FlightID = 10;
```

[Result data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrukB.png)

```
SELECT 
    PassFlightID, COUNT(*) AS 'Seats Taken' 
FROM 
    `AircraftSeating` 
LEFT JOIN 
    Passenger ON Passenger.PassAircraftSeat = AircraftSeating.AircraftSeatID
WHERE 
    PassFlightID =10;
```

[Result data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fnza.png)

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not images. ([mcve].)

Comment: What table does `PassFlightID` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [AllSeats]
      ,SUM(IF(Passenger.PassAircraftSeat  IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS [Taken Seats]
      ,COUNT(*) - SUM(IF(Passenger.PassAircraftSeat  IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS [Free Seats]
FROM Flight
INNER JOIN AircraftSeating
    ON Flight.FlightAircraftID = AircraftSeating.AircraftID
LEFT JOIN Passenger
    ON Flight.FlightID = Passenger.PassFlightID
    AND AircraftSeating.AircraftSeatID = Passenger.PassAircraftSeat
WHERE Flight.FlightID = 10;
```

Comment: Hi thanks, when I enter this query its throwing me a connection error ass soon as i enter 'WHEN' , any ideas?

Comment: @bigdog123 What's your database? SQL Server?MySQL?

Comment: its MySQL, using phpmyadmin

Comment: @bigdog123 can you try this?

Comment: Hi guys ive updated the post to make things more clear

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can express this in a single query.  I think the result is something like this:

```
SELECT f.FlightID, COUNT(*) as NumSeats,
       COUNT(p.PassAircraftSeat) as NumSeatsTaken,
       (COUNT(*) - COUNT(p.PassAircraftSeat)) as NumSeatsAvailable
FROM Flight f JOIN
     AircraftSeating acs
     ON f.FlightAircraftID = acs.AircraftID LEFT JOIN 
     Passenger p
     ON p.PassAircraftSeat = acs.AircraftSeatID
WHERE f.FlightID = 10;
```

Your data model is not clear.  Flights are generally repeated on different days, and may even have different aircraft.  It seems like a date of some sort is needed for the query.

Comment: it seems to be adding an extra seat from somewhere though.. its coming back as 26 for NumSeats but its actually 25. Any idea where it might be picking an extra value from ?

Comment: @bigdog123 . . . If the overall count is off, then that suggests that you have two passengers assigned the same seat.